# Code editing in Visual Studio like it is in Aptana Studio

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, aptana

Is there any plugins to Visual Studio that enables you to have the wonderful type-style you get in Aptana Studio, ie:

- Auto brace completion
- Auto indentation of braces (and other characters) whenever 'enter' is pressed inside the braces, like so:

Before enter:

```
{*}
```

After enter:

```
{
    *
}
```

Is it possible to make this work in Visual Studio (via plugin or otherwise)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use, for instance, Resharper, http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper, which is a pay-for plugin for code style, code refactoring and formatting. Rather advanced.

There's also Visual Assist X, http://www.wholetomato.com/, as well as JustCode, http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx and a whole lot more. Several products available, most of them for money, most of them good. =)

Comment: Yes ReSharper is a great and powerfull plugin. Very usefull!

Comment: ReSharper is very advanced, and just as fun working with. But, as you said, it´s paid-for, and although it´s _very_ good at what it does, it doesn´t cover what I was looking for.

Comment: Virtual Assist X and JustCode looks promising, although I haven´t had time trying them out.

Comment: @Marcus, wait wait wait - you're saying ReSharper doesn't insert matching braces, and indent automatically? Cause I'm pretty damned sure it does. =)

Comment: It does? Huh, must´ve missed that feature! As always, it must´ve been hidden in about 100000 other features and options in the options-menu ;)

Comment: @Marcus, http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html < It's down by "auto-insertion of delimiters". There's no direct link, unfortunately. =)

Answer (score 3):

Check [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef). It has plenty of nice stuff:

- Auto Brace Completion
- Quick Find
- Enhanced Scrollbar
- Searchable Add Reference Dialog

and others.