# What IDE (if any) to use with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ide, twitter-bootstrap

For using something like the Twitter Bootstrap framework which IDE or development tool would you think would be best for this? If you're an ASP/C# guy would you use VSS? Maybe Notepad++ or even something like ShiftEdit?

Just curious. I'm about to delve into Bootstrap to play around with it and most of my dev work is done using VSS 2010 and Notepad++. Would be nice to use a nice CSS IDE if one is available.

Comment: I want an IDE because I cannot remember all the classes provided by twitter-bootstrap. Is that the same reason you were looking the IDE for? If yes, did you find any good IDE? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: +Adil Malik - ended up using Aptana Studio and it's worked out pretty well for me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Aptana with Twiter Bootstrap and also for HTML/PHP, but is not C#, ASP ready. Anyway, here is a discussion about this subject: [Code editing in Visual Studio like it is in Aptana Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788692/code-editing-in-visual-studio-like-it-is-in-aptana-studio) Basically they are reviewing some plugins for VS which seems to be pretty good.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the Aptana link. I downloaded it and works great. I also have tried out ShiftEdit and it works fairly well as well. Great alternatives when I'm not in VSS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to add twitter bootstrap to aptana studio in current version 3.0